# How WSDLToJava in cxf works?

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

'org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava' converts wsdl to java classes.

Is it using JAXB internally?How come this command is able to generate classes like how 'xjc' creates?Can somebody explain me how it works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CXF uses xjc internally for code generation.

Refer to following for more information (from CXF official page)

In CXF versions prior to 2.3.0, the xjc plugins were shaded directly into the big cxf bundle jar. In 2.3.0, they were removed from the jar and are placed individually into the lib directory of the distribution. The xjc plugins are only code generation utilities and not used at all at runtime which is why they were pulled out.

The Apache CXF XJC-Utils subproject provides a bunch of utilities for working with JAXB to generate better or more usable code.

Currently, it consists of the following modules:

```
cxf-xjc-plugin   Provides a maven wrapper around the JAXB XJC utility
cxf-xjc-dv   Initialize fields mapped from elements/attributes with their default values
cxf-xjc-ts   Implements the toString() method
cxf-xjc-boolean  Generate getters named getXXX() for Booleans instead of isXXX()
cxf-xjc-wsdlextension    Adds extensions methods to allow generated beans to be used as WSDL4J extensors
cxf-xjc-bug671   Provides a workaround for https://jaxb.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=671
- Not needed for JAXB >=2.1.12
```

Answer (score 3):

WSDL2Java is a command line tool that generates Java classes from an existing WSDL document. Generated classes represent client stubs, server skeletons and data types that will helps you to write client side and server Java programs for Web services defined in the WSDL document.

DEFAULT_FRONTEND_NAME = "jaxws";

DEFAULT_DATABINDING_NAME = "jaxb";

For details,

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle/2.0.6/org/apache/cxf/tools/wsdlto/WSDLToJava.java

Comment: Thanks Sandeep...how this differs from xjc?xjc also creates java classes in the same fashion...Is there a relation existing wsdl2java(cxf) and xjc?...